# How to create stacked geom_bar from summarized data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~group, ~y, ~count, 
  "group_1",  "foo", 10,
  "group_1",  "bar", 20,
  "group_1",  "qux", 30,
  "group_2",  "foo", 100,
  "group_2",  "bar", 700,
  "group_2",  "qux", 150
)

dat 
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>     group     y count
#>     <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 group_1   foo    10
#> 2 group_1   bar    20
#> 3 group_1   qux    30
#> 4 group_2   foo   100
#> 5 group_2   bar   700
#> 6 group_2   qux   150
```

What I want to do is to create a stacked geom_bar that looks roughly like this (hand drawn):

[image]

Basically we want to create stacked bar based on proportionated `count` column.

How can I do that?

I am stuck with this code:

```r
dat %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=group, fill=y))
```

Which looks like this (notice that `y` is not proportionated):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fail to specify `y` aesthetics that defines the height of the bars in `aes`:

```
dat %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = group, y = count, fill = y), stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

---

If you need to normalize:

```
dat %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x=group, y = ave(count, group, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x)), fill=y), stat = 'identity') + 
    ylab('Proportion')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem `FUN` not `FUNC`.